# how to select rows without sorting in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I want to select list of records using Id. I am having order like **254,265,10,258** like that. I want to select the same order. But when i write a query in sql server it is automatically take the order **10,254,258,265** like that.

How to rectify this using query in sql server 2008?

I am having 1000 records like that. Please help me any one?

Comment: Post your query please.

Comment: If you want a specific order, you **must** supply an explicit `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

Comment: marc_s is right. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Comment: what does the rest of the record look like?  Why do you need that order? Is there any logical way looking at those records to tell what the order you want would be (like a timestamp)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want specific order like 254,265,10,258, use a temp table or table varialbe

```
declare @IDs table
(
    seq  int identity(1,1),
    ID   int
)
insert into @IDs (ID) select 254
insert into @IDs (ID) select 265
insert into @IDs (ID) select 10
insert into @IDs (ID) select 258

SELECT *
FROM   @IDs i INNER JOIN yourtable t ON i.DI = t.ID
ORDER BY i.seq
```

another way is specify the ordering in ORDER BY clause

```
ORDER BY (CASE ID when 254 then 1 when 265 then 2 when 10 then 3 when 258 then 4 end)
```

No matter what, you will still need a ORDER BY clause

Comment: So, He must use 1000 case condition statement for the 1000 records.